# How to modify a PHP json_decode into a jquery.getJSON()?

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

I am a newer for study php and jQuery, I tried many times myself, but also not work well.

How to modify a PHP json_decode into a jQuery.getJSON()?  I want modify all the PHPcode into javascript.

```
    $json_data = file_get_contents("data.txt"); 
    $data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    if($data){
    $num = 1;
    foreach ($data as $result) {
    ?>
        $.ajax({
        url: "page2.php", 
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST', 
        data: "value=<?php echo $result['name']; ?>",
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#result<?php echo $num; ?>").html(data);
        }
    <?php
    $num++
    }
    }
    ?>
```

json tree:

```
[
 {"name" : "name1"},
 {"name" : "name2"},
 {"name" : "name3"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the text file is json then the following should work as JSON is a subset of javascript.

```
<?php
$json_data = file_get_contents("data.txt");
echo "var json_data = $json_data;";
?>

for (var i = 0; i<json_data.length; i++) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "page2.php", 
        dataType: "html",
        type: 'POST', 
        data: "value="+json_data[i].name,
        success: function(data){ 
            $("#result"+String(i+1)).html(data);
        }
}
```